# How to copy address on node translate action

Tags: i18n-l10n, location

My website is an i18n web site. When it's time to manage content with a location field (address) I need to manually copy the address. Is there a way to make the location copy automatically on translated node?

Let's say I have node type Retail. This node type contains a Location (Field) provide with Location Module for Address purpose.

**Use case:**

User clicks on Add Retail (in French first). He filled the Location field like (Address, city province, country etc.). After that, the user clicks on save and then clicks on the Translate button. The user chooses to translate in English. The Address field that was previously entered in French is empty and the user needs to enter it again.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I Clarify it. Anybody have an idea how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying the content of the field you can try the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module  and only make some fields translatable. It will be much less messy than any kind of copying, where you'll end up with 2 or more copies of data that should actually just be one piece of data.

If you enable Entity Translation on your site you shouldn't enable Translation for this Address field, but you should enable it for other fields that you want to be translated.

> Allows (fieldable) entities to be translated into different languages, by introducing entity/field translation for the new translatable fields capability in Drupal 7. Maintained by the Drupal core i18n team.
>
> This project does not replace the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) project, which focuses on enabling a full multilingual workflow for site admins/builders. Some features, e.g. content language negotiation or taxonomy translation, might overlap but most of them are unrelated.

I'm using this on a multilingual website. I don't want the product status field to be translatable:

[image: Added translation option for fields]

But the body should be translatable:

[image]